# 3d normal map not working correctly in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, phong

I want to add a normal map to my mesh and when I applyed to it the model becoms rendered as flat not smooth and I don't get the effect I want.

Here is my material code:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
            {
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/text/diffuse.jpg' ),
                ambient: 0x030303,
                color: 0xdddddd,
                specular: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/text/Specular03.jpg' ),
                shininess: 30,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
                normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/text/wrap_NM.jpg' ),
                metal: false,
                skining: true
            }
        );
```

How can I set up normal map correctly?

normal map is in TIF if that means something. (I think not but just in case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way, the problem was with TIF image, I only converted that to JPG and it works just fine.